# A pattern to "atomically" update a pair of objects

Tags: object-oriented-design, synchronization, state

Is there a standard pattern in OOP to kind of "atomically" update a pair of objects, like a pair of bank accounts on a transaction?

I would like to have somehow a single public method exposed that does it all at once, but can only come up with ways of doing it by making *two* calls of public methods to update objects separately.

I am currently experimenting with *Racket*, but i would appreciate examples in any language, or a description of a standard pattern.

---

Here is an example of what i have experimented in *Ruby* (with which i am more comfortable than with *Racket*).  I am not concerned with locking here, just with class interface.

```rb
class Account
  def initialize(total)
    @total = total
  end

  def total
    @total
  end

  def transfer_to(another, sum:)
    change_total_by(-sum)
    another.change_total_by(sum)
  end

  protected

    def change_total_by(sum)
      @total += sum
    end

end

a = Account.new(10)
b = Account.new(20)
a.transfer_to(b, sum: 5)
print "New a.total = #{ a.total },\nnew b.total = #{ b.total }"
```

This works using `protected` instead of `private`.

Comment: Could you expand on what you're trying to do, and what you already tried? As it is now, the question is a bit unclear and I'd just answer with “*acquire lock on each object, update both, unlock*” or with “*use database transactions*”. Which is probably not addressing your actual problem.

Comment: I am only playing with OOP in *Racket*.  The question is not about data integrity, but about the class interface: it does not seem possible to me to expose somehow a single public method (or maybe this is not how it should be done?) to update both states without exposing public methods for updating just one state.  I suspect the answer can be very language-specific, but if i see the keywords, maybe i'll be able to search for it myself.  If this is not clear, maybe i'll add an example later.

Comment: When thinking about OOP, you should not be thinking about methods, but about objects. It is objects that encapsulate behavior, not methods. And sometimes, you have to create new type of object to ensure the correct behavior.

Answer (score 7):

You can abstract the transaction as an object in itself, which then provides a single interface to manage the transaction and its participants. First property of transactions, Atomicity satisfies your requirement of atomicity/single point.

I.e.  something like this:

```
public class Transaction {
    ...
    private Account _source;
    private Account _destination;

    public void Commit() {
        lock( _globalAccountWriteLock )
        lock( _source )
        lock( _destination )
        lock( this ) {
            try {
                UpdateSource( _source );
                UpdateDestiantion( _destination );
            }
            catch( Exception e ) {
                // Rollback
            }
        }
    }
```

The important part is, **you have to use respective locks for every access to these three objects** for it to work.

Comment: Though the multithreading may need additional care, the question is mainly about the design of object interfaces, so IMHO your answer misses the point.

Comment: There is a lock ordering deadlock in this code. You could solve it by by acquiring a global lock before acquiring the account locks.

Comment: I do not agree about "the answer misses the point". The Transaction object (with a Commit method) is a requested OOP pattern. But I'll reformulate the answer a bit more clearly.

Comment: Given that you take the global lock first, are the other locks even needed?

Comment: You could even do without the locks by having queue of transaction objects, executing them separately and enforcing that any changes in accounts needs to happen in transaction object.

Comment: Could you tell please how and where `UpdateSource` and `UpdateDestiantion` are defined?

Comment: Not really, you asked for a pattern and that's what this is. The idea is that ensuring atomicity isn't the responsibility of either individual account, but of a dedicated object. Ultimately you _do_ need two method calls, you just wrap them in a Transaction to get the guarantee you requested.

Comment: Both Updates are defined in the Transaction and their implementation is transaction-specific. There can be different transactions according to different business cases/workflows.

Comment: @Kaerber, but the Updates defined in Transaction can only modify Accounts through their public methods, so what public methods would the Accounts have?

Comment: Well, the methods of Account objects heavily depend on their behavior, and their behavior depends on a task at hand. An account in an ad agency is very different from a savings account in a bank. You should strive to model real world entities and their behavior/operations.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a `public addAmount(amount)` method, your `class Account` could have a `public addAmountFrom(otherAccount, amount)` method which automatically checks the other account and performs the counter-operation on it.

When each balance-change of a account **must** specify another account, you also automatically enforce the "no entry without counter-entry" rule of double-entry bookkeeping.

The counter-operation could be done through a `private` or `protected` method `subtractAmountTo(this, amount)`. Most OOP languages allow private and protected methods to be called from objects of the same class. It should be private because the method assumes that the counter-entry is taken care off by the caller.

Comment: Which methods would be exposed as public? How a method sent to one `Account` can change another `Account`?

Comment: @Alexey `addAmount` wouldn't exist anymore. The `addAmountFrom` method would be public. There would also need to be a `subtractAmountTo` method which is called from `addAmountFrom` on the `otherAccount`. This method would have to be protected or private (most OOP programming languages allow to call private methods of other objects which are of the same class).

Answer (score 0):

I think i've found a satisfactory solution myself.  Here is a *Ruby* version:

```rb
class TransactionService
  def initialize
    @accounts = {}
  end

  def register_account(account_id, deposit_proc:, withdrawal_proc:)
    @accounts.store(account_id,
                    :deposit_proc    => deposit_proc,
                    :withdrawal_proc => withdrawal_proc)
  end

  def forget_account(account_id)
    @accounts.delete(account_id)
  end

  def transfer(sender_id:, receiver_id:, sum:)
    @accounts[sender_id  ][:withdrawal_proc][sum]
    @accounts[receiver_id][:deposit_proc   ][sum]
  end
end

class Account
  def initialize(total, transaction_service:)
    @total = total

    transaction_service.register_account(self.public_id,
        deposit_proc:    proc do |sum| change_total_by(sum)  end,
        withdrawal_proc: proc do |sum| change_total_by(-sum) end)
  end

  def total
    @total
  end

  def public_id
    self.object_id  # just for simplicity
  end

  private

    def change_total_by(sum)
      @total += sum
    end

end

ts = TransactionService.new
a = Account.new(10, transaction_service: ts)
b = Account.new(20, transaction_service: ts)

print "Initial a.total = #{ a.total },\n" \
      "initial b.total = #{ b.total }.\n" \
      "---\n"

ts.transfer(sender_id:   a.public_id,
            receiver_id: b.public_id,
            sum:         5)

print "New a.total = #{ a.total },\n" \
      "new b.total = #{ b.total }.\n"
```

I do not care about locking, but it can be implemented easily inside `TransactionService#transfer`.

Comment: This is just a general idea, this exact code would not be very efficient, i suppose.

Comment: Probably instead of `Account` there should be `Bank`, as there are much fewer banks than accounts.  Then each bank would have to manage its accounts.